# Function bound to React Component Cannot Be Passed to Child Component and Rebound

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with this issue of context:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    let _handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={_handleChange} id='input'/>
        <label htmlFor='input'> Upload </label>
        {this.state.error && <span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class FooClosure extends Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    let self = this // this will always be FooClosure
    debugger // local this context will be Foo
    this.setState({ error: true, errorMessage: 'Some error happened'})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FooClosure />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying setState inside a function defined in a parent component that gets bound in the child component. My understanding of Javascript means that `this` would then be the child component, but `this.setState` is always executed in the context of FooClosure. Can anyone help me understand why this is?

I can fix this easily by defining `handleChange = (event, self) => ...` but I dont think I should have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're defining `this` in your `handleChange` method, you're explicitly telling the program to look at its current scope where the function is being written. Passing it as a prop will only run the function in its written scope, not redefine `this`, nor will redefining it in your `Foo` class prove helpful.

Imagine `FooClosure` and `Foo` are in two separate rooms and somehow became sentient beings. `FooClosure` has the ability to make pizzas. `Foo` has the ability to call `FooClosure` and ask for a pizza to be made. The problem here is `Foo` is asking `FooClosure` to make the pizza, but all the ingredients and the only working oven are in `Foo`'s room.

The best thing to do in this situation is to move your `handleChange` method into your `Foo` class so `this` can reference `Foo` and not `FooClosure` which in turn allows you to set the state of `Foo`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ 
      error: true, 
      errorMessage: 'Some error happened',
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { handleChange } = this
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={handleChange} id='input'/>
        <label htmlFor='input'> Upload </label>
        {this.state.error && <span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class FooClosure extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FooClosure />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now this of course would make your `FooClosure` class redundant. If you needed to handle anything based off of the onChange in `Foo`, you can use this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { handleFooClosureMethod } = this.props.handleFooClosureMethod
    handleFooClosureMethod(args)
    this.setState({ 
      error: true, 
      errorMessage: 'Some error happened',
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { handleChange } = this
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={handleChange} id='input'/>
        <label htmlFor='input'> Upload </label>
        {this.state.error && <span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class FooClosure extends Component {
  handleChange = args => {
    //handle this method
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo handleFooClosureMethod={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FooClosure />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Keep in mind the latter will fire every time the onChange event occurs in your `Foo` class.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should write it.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={this.props.handleChange} id='input'/>
        <label htmlFor='input'> Upload </label>
        {this.props.error && <span>{this.props.errorMessage}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class FooClosure extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {error: false, errorMessage: ''};
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ error: true, errorMessage: 'Some error happened'})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} error={this.state.error} errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check this out and try it yourself here: https://github.com/jdetle/weird-js-examples

Comment: That doesn't work nor does

`onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange.call(this, event)}`

the only solution I've found is

`handleChange(event, self) { ... } `

and

`onChange = { (event) => this.props.handleChange(event, this) }`

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful, but it is not entirely accurate. The problem is that either by binding it or establishing it as an anonymous function, it cannot be rebound to the new context of Foo.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.props.handleChange.bind(this)
    debugger
  }

  render() {
    console.log('foo state', this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={this.handleChange} id='input'/>
        <label htmlFor='input'> Upload </label>
        {this.state.error && <span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class FooClosure extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange;
  }
  handleChange() {
    let self = this // this will now be Foo
    debugger // local this context will be Foo
    this.setState({ error: true, errorMessage: 'Some error happened'})
  }
  render() {
    console.log('closure state', this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```